# How to get difference of two subquery in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get difference from a document. I am able to do it by breaking it into query by query. But i want to know is there any way so i can get it via single query.
Below is the approach i am using. I am using nodeJs for API creation

Document structure :

```
     {
         "_id":{"$oid":"5e72084442164229a07b18bd"},
          "id":"5e7205a4d2273b135c9ac43c",
          "type":{"$numberInt":"2"},
     },
    {
         "_id":{"$oid":"5e72084442164229a07b18bd"},
          "id":"5e7205a4d2273b135c9ac43c",
          "type":{"$numberInt":"1"},
    },
    {
         "_id":{"$oid":"5e72084442164229a07b18bd"},
          "id":"5e7205a4d2273b135c9ac43c",
          "type":{"$numberInt":"2"},
    },
    {
         "_id":{"$oid":"5e72084442164229a07b18bd"},
          "id":"5e7205a4d2273b135c9ac43c",
          "type":{"$numberInt":"2"},      
    },
    {
         "_id":{"$oid":"5e72084442164229a07b18bd"},
          "id":"5e7205a4d2273b135c9ac43c",
          "type":{"$numberInt":"1"},      
    },
```

I want to get differnce between counts of type 2 and type 1

like

**count of type 2 - count of type 1**

I have used below approach and able to get total but i want to know is there any better approach

```
app.get('/totalVote',(req,res)=>{
    reposnseObj = {
        status: false,
        totalCnt : 0
    }
    let totalCnt = 0
    let upvoteCnt = 0
    let downVoteCnt = 0
    if(db){
        //downvote counting
        query = {id:req.query.id,type:1}
        db.collection("points").countDocuments(
            query
        ).then(
            result =>{
                downVoteCnt = result
                //upvote counting
                query = {id:req.query.id,type:2}
                db.collection("points").countDocuments(
                    query
                ).then(
                    result =>{
                        upvoteCnt = result

                        // totalCnt
                        totalCnt = upvoteCnt -downVoteCnt
                        reposnseObj = {
                            status: true,
                            totalCnt : totalCnt
                        }
                        res.send(reposnseObj)
                    }
                )
            }
        );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and get two separate counts (using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html)) and then [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/index.html) the results:

```
db.collection("points").aggregate([
    {
        $match: { id:req.query.id }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            downVoteCnt: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$type", 1 ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
            upVoteCnt: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$type", 2 ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            result: { $subtract: [ "$upVoteCnt", "$downVoteCnt" ] }
        }
    }
])
```